# Tips/resources for structuring C code?

Tags: c, makefile, directory-structure

Does anyone have tips/resources for how to, in the best way, structure your C code projects? (Different folders etc.) And how do you know when it's good to split code into separate files? And what is an example of a good Makefile?

My project is not that big, but I wanna start to structure my code at an early stage..

Answer (score 2):

Structuring code needs some experience but mostly common sense.

For splitting code, you usually go for readability: conceptually coherent functions/datatypes should go in the same file. You can take c standard library as a good example. It is better to keep your data structure definitions and function declarations in separate headers. This allows you to use the data structures as part of a compilation unit even if you have not defined all the functions.

Files that provide similar functionality should go in the same directory. It is good to avoid deep directory structure (1 level deep is best) as that complicates building the project unnecessarily.

I think Makefiles are OK for small projects, but become unwieldy for bigger ones. For really serious work (if you want to distribute your code, create an installer etc) you may want to look at cmake, scons, etc.

Have a look at the GNU coding standards: http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html

Look at the gnu make manual for a simple example Makefile. You can also pick up any opensource project and look at the Makefile. Browsing code repositories in sourceforge.net may be useful.

Comment: If you're going to talk about the GNU standards, you should mention `automake`. It saves so much time making standards-compliant `Makefile`s and is still better than CMake (a little less pretty, certainly, but definitely better).

Comment: That is debatable, and looks like the community is moving away from automake. I have no doubt that gnu autotools have been extremely useful for many projects over many years, but there are newer tools which have learnt from the experience:

Comment: here are some links: http://lwn.net/Articles/188693/           and http://www.scons.org/wiki/SconsVsOtherBuildTools and http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=976922

Comment: Anyone that moves away experiences only problems. Projects that matter all stick to automake.

Answer (score 1):

Read one of the many C coding standards available on the internet and follow one that looks reasonable for your requirements. A few links:

- [GNU Coding Standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html)
- [C Coding Standards at IRAM](http://iram.fr/IRAMFR/TA/computer/coding.pdf) (pdf)
- [Indian Hill C Style and Coding Standards](http://www.psgd.org/paul/docs/cstyle/cstyle.htm)

The following books also contain effective guidelines on writing good C code:

- [The C Programming Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/)
- [The Practice of Programming](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=020161586X)
- [The Elements of Programming Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style)

Comment: +1 for suggesting The Practice of Programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes overlooked, but security is an issue in big projects. Here's some advice about how to [program securely](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/CERT+C+Secure+Coding+Standard).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idiom I like:

Declare `struct`s in a header so that their size is known by client code. Then declare init and deinit functions to the following convention:

- The first parameter is a `struct foo*`.
- The return type is a `struct foo*`.
- If they might fail, the last parameter is either `int*` (simplest), `enum foo_error*` (if there are several ways it can fail that the calling code might care about) or `GError**` (if you're writing GLib-style code).

`foo_init()` and `foo_deinit()` return `NULL` if the first parameter is `NULL`. They also return the first parameter.

Why do it this way? Calling code doesn't have to allocate heap space for the structure, it can go on the stack. If you are allocating it on the heap, though, the following works nicely:

```
struct foo* a_foo = foo_init(malloc(sizeof(*a_foo)));
if (a_foo == NULL) {
  /* Ruh-oh, allocation failure... */
}
free(foo_deinit(a_foo));
```

Everything works nicely even if `a_foo == NULL` when `foo_deinit` is called.